# Как понимать sha3-256 - что именно означает число 256 в название функции?

Tags: хеширование, sha

Преобразовываю любым генератором в онлайне строку в sha3-256. На выходе получаю строку в 64 символа, размером 64 байта(utf8) или 128(unicode) - коли верить счётчику символов. Что в итоге означает 256 в названии функции? И вообще, как понять размер хэша 224, 256, 384, 512? - в википедии написано. Я думал это размер получаемой в итоге строки. Но получается, что это вроде как не так.

Comment: Любой хэш даёт на выходе набор байт, никаких utf8 или unicode для хэша не существует. Если вместо байт вы получаете символы в какой-то кодировке, значит ваш генератор выполняет какую-то постобработку. А какую именно — выясняйте уже в документации вашего генератора.

Comment: Вероятно, ваш генератор преобразует байты в строку, представляющую собой 16-ричное представление числа (цифры 0-9, a-f). Тогда на 1 байт хэша приходится 2 символа в итоговой строке. Тогда 64 символа — это 32 байта, а 32 байта умножаем на 8 бит — это 256 бит. Хэш-функция sha3-256 называется так потому, что она генерирует хэш длиной ровно 256 бит.

Comment: @andreymal запостите как ответ?

Comment: @Kromster думаю, могут найтись люди, способные написать его лучше и развёрнутее чем я

Comment: @andreymal не скромничайте. Лучше хороший написанный ответ, чем идеальный и ненаписанный ;-)  Тем более, что *"Используйте комментарии для запроса дополнительной информации или предложения улучшений. Избегайте публикации ответа на вопросы в комментариях."*

Answer (score 5):

@andreymal:

> Любой хэш даёт на выходе набор байт, никаких utf8 или unicode для хэша не существует. Если вместо байт вы получаете символы в какой-то кодировке, значит ваш генератор выполняет какую-то постобработку. А какую именно — выясняйте уже в документации вашего генератора
> Вероятно, ваш генератор преобразует байты в строку, представляющую собой 16-ричное представление числа (цифры 0-9, a-f). Тогда на 1 байт хэша приходится 2 символа в итоговой строке. Тогда 64 символа — это 32 байта, а 32 байта умножаем на 8 бит — это 256 бит. Хэш-функция sha3-256 называется так потому, что она генерирует хэш длиной ровно 256 бит.